# I want to make user type the length on the list and then put enter the value in the list c#

Tags: c#

I want to make user type the length on the list and then put enter the value in the list c#

I already put inside for loop but it doesn't work

```
public static void AddValueToList()
{
    _values.Add(new double()); 
    double numberofValues = _values.Count; 
    for ( int i = 0; i < _values.Count; i++)
    {
    int numberOfValues;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter size of index:");
    numberOfValues = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    _values[i] = ReadDouble($"Enter the {i + 1}st value:");

    }

}
```

Well, there is no error but the value of length doesn't store in the program

Comment: Could you please show use the contents of your `ReadDouble` method?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Is the functionality you're looking for this: User enters number `x` (int) then user is asked to enter number `y` (double or int?) and then `values[x]` (if by index) or `values[x-1]` (if it is the x-th number) will be set the `y`?

Comment: Problem solved just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the list and get the number of values and iterate to add the values to the list

```
public static void AddValueToList()
{
  _values = new List<double>(); 
  int numberOfValues;
  Console.WriteLine("Enter size of index:");
  numberOfValues = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
  {
      _values.Add(ReadDouble($"Enter the {i + 1}st value:"));
  }
```

}